# I can't download my iCloud calender anymore

Tags: powershell, batch-file, download, icloud

I had a bat file which downloaded my iCloud calendar every hour. the link used was found via the iCloud site (the calendar is public shared). It has an webcal:// url but according to Apple's support you have to change this to http.

Using explorer of chrome, this file does not download.
In Chrome: {"reason":"Invalid or missing Origin header","error":1}
In Explorer: file seems to start, but then it says: "can't download ..."

My bat file:

```
@echo off
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://p20-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/1/...', 'D:\Backup\cal.ics')"
pause
```

The code above gives me:

Exception calling "downloadfile" with "2" arguments: the remote server returned an error: 421 misdirected request.

This used to work fine, not anymore it seems.

Any thoughts? Anyone else doing something similar?

Tried replacing http with https, but no luck. Searching if iCloud made some changes didn't turn up any results.

Comment: Sounds like a software problem. You might want to try asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Using the link without the Powershell, does it download?

Comment: No, it does not. Using the link provided in Chrome (inserting in address bar) gives me:

{"reason":"Invalid or missing Origin header","error":1}

In explorer: explorer asks to download or open, when choosing download: can't download 'xyz'

Comment: I am experiencing this also. At some point this month (I am guessing May 6th based on yours and others' reports), subscribed icalendar cals in google cal stopped working. Google still shows me previously entered data but no new events. Using curl to download the webcal link gives me "Invalid or missing Origin header" (after changing "protocol" from webcal to http, then https).

I don't know if they broke things in trying to migrate to https or something else, but the issue definitely appears to be at Apple's end. See also https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7963704?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue that worked for me.

I had some calendars that had the error

> {"reason":"Invalid or missing Origin header","error":1}

and some that didn't. Then I noticed that the ones that I could download without any trouble started with 'webcal://p05-' while those that had the error started with 'webcal://p45-'. So I simply unticked Public Calendar and clicked OK before selecting the calendar again and ticking Public Calendar. If that generates a URL starting with 'webcal://p45-', copy it to the browser and try downloading it, if not, try again until you get the right URL.

Comment: This worked for me.

After a few times I noticed I only got a "p20-" url. I tried that one and it worked.

Note: not all "p20-" urls seem to work. It's a trial and error process I guess. Thx Jeppe!

Answer (score 2):

Did you recently enable Apple's Two-Factor Authentication?  I was getting the same error as you when trying to access a public Apple Calendar from someone's account -- it worked fine and then started giving the "invalid or missing origin header" information.  I had that person turn off Two-Factor Authentication and then I regenerated the Public Calendar link (using iCloud.com) and now it works fine.  Given that one of Apple's latest updates really started pushing the Two-Factor Authentication, it may have been turned on without fully realizing it (my mom managed to turn it on and didn't even know what it was when I asked her about it).

John